# Can not run process delete

Tags: flask

Can't run process delete. Just stopped after send_file...
Yes, i know that return can only happen once... But i don't know how to call function delete...

```
@app.route('/download<file>', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def download(file):
    got_file = file
    return send_file(got_file, as_attachment=True)
    return redirect(url_for('delete', got_file=got_file))

@app.route('/delete<got_file>')
def delete(got_file):
    os.remove(got_file)
    return 'File deleted!'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call the function from inside your download function:

```
@app.route('/download<file>', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def download(file):
    got_file = file
    send_file(got_file, as_attachment=True)
    return delete(got_file)


@app.route('/delete<got_file>')
def delete(got_file):
    os.remove(got_file)
    return 'File deleted!'
```

Comment: No, that's doesn't work. File deleted before send to customer and we got a error of server.

Comment: You're right, sorry, I updated the answer to first send the file, then delete it

Comment: Yeah, now that's deleted, but file impossible to download, because it deleted before it... 
I was trying this already.

Comment: I tried to use time.sleep(10), but function send_file in this case can't allow to download file.

Comment: But did you reupload the file after deleting it the first time?

Comment: Yes. Of course i did it. Separate these functions working good but together...